# Chrome allow audio and video access settings

Tags: google-chrome

I am trying to put together a small webpage for my daughter that uses speech input to test her knowledge of various words that she is supposed to know on sight.

The problem is every time she hits the answer button it asks for microphone permission.  I hit allow and it saves as an exception in my chrome media settings as ask.

Everything I am reading online is telling me that for it to remember the settings and set to allow, it needs to be on an https server.

This site I use to test my webcam is not on an https but still saves as allow and doesn't ask again.  http://testmycam.net

How do they do it without an ssl cert?

Comment: ok, so the flash settings are what dicate that for the media settings. Idk why but I thought they would be separate settings. Thank you .

Comment: The restrictions you talk about are for the html5 `getUserMedia` API. Flash doesn't have such restrictions. Maybe you could achieve it through a Chrome extension though. But didn't tested.

Comment: Actually it has to be a [packaged app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app)

Comment: This looks promising.  I had begun playing with extension development a few months ago.  Looks like it's time to start researching again, lol.  Thank you very much for all of the information Kaiido.